# Using Mid and IF together: What if I have several variables in my logical test?

Tags: excel, if-statement

So my formula looks like this in my bar:
=IF(MID([@[bin_id]],9,1)="a", MID([@[bin_id]],9,1), "PALLET")

My only issue is I want to use several variables for my logical test.  Basically I want to say this:

If my Mid formula is equal to "a, b, c, d, e, f, g" then leave it alone.  If it does not equal those variables, then return the text "pallet".

I am doing this because my cell "bin_id" has bin locations, unfortunately pallet locations are labeled shorter so when I use my MID formula it doesn't return the variable I want for them.

Answer (score 3):

Alternate solution:

```
=IF(OR(MID([@[bin id]],9,1)={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"}),MID([@[bin id]],9,1),"PALLET")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"},MATCH(MID([@[bin_id]],9,1),{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"},0)),"PALLET")
```

OR:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(MID([@[bin_id]],9,1),{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"},0)),MID([@[bin_id]],9,1),"PALLET")
```

Comment: I can only give one upvote...wanted to give two..one for formula and one for speed of answer...and dang it on the last part! Take a coffee before answering next time! 8)

Comment: It is telling me I put in too many arguments for that function.  And yes, kudos for very fast reply!  Is there any more information you would want to fix my problem?

Comment: Just saw it.  Thank you so much!